# Can I USB boot Windows XP or 7 on my Intel Core 2 duo iMac 5,2 1.83GHz 2009?

Tags: windows, imac

Can I USB boot Windows XP or 7 on my Intel Core 2 duo iMac 5,2 1.83GHz 2009?

I don't care what version of Windows has to go on; I just need to run some XP apps. 7 would be great but plech...
There's gotta be a way.
I've got 10.5.8 running now, does it matter?
Can't (won't, way too much installed on it) reformat my drive. May as well swap out drives...

Just a simple USB boot. No garbage.

Comment: if there is no unique reason to run it solely on your hardware: you can easily run it in [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) in MacOS. Install virtualbox and additions and then use the Windows XP-DVD/CD to install.

Comment: Windows hates being booted from an external drive. VM would be the best way, if you can find one old enough.

Comment: When you say USB, do you mean a flash drive, or an external USB hard drive?

Comment: Virtual box sounds good, i tried to find out about VPC but this new interweb sucks donkeyballs... ill look it up...    if i could boot off an external drive that would be news to me... im new to the first gen intel mac scene so im open to any option that works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all [an Intel Core 2 duo iMac5,2 1.83GHz](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-2-duo-1.83-17-inch-specs.html) is a 2006 model year Mac. The OP's question shows a 2009 model year. All 2006 though 2009 iMacs can not BIOS boot Windows from USB drives. The drivers include in the Boot Camp Support Software (also known as the Windows Support Software) are designed for a BIOS booting Windows. While other operating systems may be able to EFI boot from 2006 though 2009 Macs, attempting to EFI boot a Windows XP SP2 or Windows 7 SP1 installer should result in failure.

Comment: I know all these crossover first gen chips are iffy and glitchomatic so it doesn't surprise me to be failtastic. I paid $30 bucks for it so im used to being a sharpshooter from the G3minitower era.      I also bought a M1 mini so im 4 for 4 on the  first gen hit parade.

Comment: The Mac has USB 2.0 ports which are fairly slow compared to the internal drive. Your easiest option would be to get a larger internal drive and either install a 32 bit Windows (XP SP2, Vista or 7) by using the Boot Camp Assistant (which might require a firmware and/or OS X upgrade) or run a 32 or 64 bit Windows in a VM (such as an older version of VirtualBox). Of course, running in a VM would be considerably slower than a dual boot arrangement. Or, offload files to an USB drive until you have enough free space on the existing internal drive.